# Best practice for multilingual categories and products?

Tags: product, category, url-rewrite, language

I think it is very important question for setting up a multilingual store with Magento.
The main problem here I am facing is URL rewriting for categories names for different language.

I have this situation. Let's assume there is 2 store views English and Russian.
So my URL for categories look like this:

```
http://domain.com/en/products/computers/intel
http://domain.com/ru/produkcija/kompjutery/intel
```

As you can see category Products is translated to Russian as produkcija(URL key) and Computers to kompjutery(URL key). After this I did redirects for these categories from Russian to English and English to Russian.

When creating a product I would have to do this redirect for products as well. For example computers/intel <-> kompjutery/intel

I would like to say that what I got so far works with writing all redirects manually and I think it is not very convinient, especially when I need to add many products. So I am asking maybe there is a better approach for this?

Comment: I don't know much about it. Does it mean thar urls will look like en.domain.com?

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation. I took a look at sephora.com but their url structure is not suitable for my website. What I would like is to have domain.com/category-en and domain.com/ru/category-ru. So I assume that I need to create folder /ru in the root and place index.php and .htaccess there. Is it a right approach to avoid all these rewrites? I would be grateful for an answer.

Comment: But the thing is that my website is only for one country and I only need a translated version of the same website and the main problem is to link between different categories names for each language when a user switches a language so he would stay on the same category but with different url name. For example,I saw websites where switching to another language leads to a homepage of an another language. Does multi-domain work this way?

Comment: Ok, I understand. So I am aware that in Magento I can leave categories URL Key unchanged for both languages. If I understood you correctly and country market is not very large I could leave for instance mywebsite.com/computers for English and mywebsite.com/computers for Russian NOT mywebsite.com/ru/kompjutery for Russian?

Comment: Thank yo very much for making it clear.

Comment: @KirillRyzhkov did you ever solve this? If so could you share your solution here

Comment: @David Manners Yes I found a solution here https://github.com/Vinai/VinaiKopp_StoreUrlRewrites. Just copy files to your Magento installation and you can write different url key for other languages. And untick URL rewrite

Comment: Feel free to add that as an answer :-)

Comment: @David Manners ok)

Answer (score 2):

Solution is [here](https://github.com/Vinai/VinaiKopp_StoreUrlRewrites). Just copy files to your Magento installation and you can write different url key for other languages. And untick URL rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessary if you use the Magento option that puts the store code in the URL:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But putting store code to URL is not a solution for me. I have already tried it. It makes url structure this way: domain.com/en/category-en and domain.com/ru/category-ru. I don't need /en in the url for the main site. So the solution was to make /ru folder inside the root and set Add store code to URL to NO